# from functor of points to stacks (or almost)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, stacks, algebraic-stacks

I want to have a better "working knowledge" of stacks.  However every time that I approach the topic, I finish hitting a wall of technical details. They are essential, but I don't need them for now.

So, I am wondering where I can find a "naive" description of stacks. Something better than the story of the functor of points at the level of the book Geometry of schemes, but without all the technical weight of the Stack project or Martin Olsson's book.

I am ok if there are small white lies here and there; and if the generality is not as high as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You misspelled the name of Martin Olsson.  One excellent reference is Barbara Fantechi's paper "Stacks for Everybody".

Comment: You might have a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309265/good-introductory-references-on-moduli-stacks-for-arithmetic-objects/311193#311193) and its various answers.

Comment: Kai Behrend, _Introduction to algebraic stacks_ seems to be really interesting! See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12765/) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2124).

Comment: I do not understand what exactly are you looking for...